# Draw and resize an image over a specific region

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I'm creating a control that inherits from a `Windows.Forms.Panel` and has a specific region onto which I want to draw an image.

This code draws the image over the region I want, but doesn't stretch it.

```
private void PaintPanel(Graphics _g)
{
    _g.FillRegion(new SolidBrush(BorderColor), BorderRegion);
    _g.FillRegion(new TextureBrush(ContentImage), ContentRegion);
    regionNeedsRefresh = false;
}
```

This code draws the image over the rectangle I want, and stretches it to fit the rectangle, but it doesn't draw over the exact region I want:

```
private void PaintPanel(Graphics _g)
{
    _g.FillRegion(new SolidBrush(BorderColor), BorderRegion);
    _g.DrawImage(ContentImage, ContentRegion.GetBounds(_g));
    regionNeedsRefresh = false;
}
```

So what I need is a bit of both solutions I'm guessing...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Graphics.DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx), and simply set the `Clip` property of the `Graphics` object to the `Region` you want to draw in before and after the operation.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but that doesn't seem to draw in front of other regions I have painted with `Graphics.FillRegion`

Comment: I've worked out why it wasn't appearing. However it doesn't solve my problem. If the image is bigger than my panel, it doesn't get resized, only clipped.